# node red admin login failed

Tags: node-red

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/access-node-red-dashboard-anywhere-digital-ocean/#:%7E:text=install%20node-red-admin%20package%20to%20make%20it%20available%20globally%3A) to create a login for node red.

From what I can gather node-red admin is built into node red so why would I need to install a package? I get an error when using the tutorial code trying

```
npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red-admin
```

Linux terminal this command works from the tutorial code:

```
node-red-admin hash-pw
```

To retrieve the password `hash` and `sudo nano ~/.node-red/settings.js` following the tutorial to uncomment the correct lines on my end it looks like this:

```
/** To password protect the Node-RED editor and admin API, the following
 * property can be used. See http://nodered.org/docs/security.html for details.
 */
adminAuth: {
    type: "credentials",
    users: [{
        username: "ben",
        password: "supersecretP@$$word",
        permissions: "*"
    }]
},

/** The following property can be used to enable HTTPS
 * This property can be either an object, containing both a (private) key
 * and a (public) certificate, or a function that returns such an object.
 * See http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener
 * for details of its contents.
 */
```

And then thru nano writing the file and doing a `sudo reboot` I cant login with this username and password, any ideas to try?

[image]

Comment: The `password` fields need to be hashed with bcrypt. Your settings.js password field is hashed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password you are storing in your settings.js file should be a **hash** that is generated from your password.
You can generate this hash with the tool from your cli use

> **node-red-admin hash-pw**

or

> **node -e "console.log(require('bcryptjs').hashSync(process.argv[1], 8));" your-password-here**

After entering your password a string of hash will appear, copy it and insert it in the settings file:

```
adminAuth: {
    type: "credentials",
    users: [{
        username: "ben",
        password: "$2b$08$wuAqPiKJlVN27eF5qJp.RuQYuy6ZYONW7a/UWYxDTtwKFCdB8F19y",
       permissions: "*"
    }]
},
```

It should look something like this.

I suggest you to read the [documentation page](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/securing-node-red#editor--admin-api-security) in-depth to properly secure your node-red instance before opening it to public use.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong here:

```
adminAuth: {
    type: "credentials",
    users: [{
        username: "ben",
        password: "supersecretP@$$word",
        permissions: "*"
    }]
},
```

The `password` needs to be `hash` not the password I was hoping to use to log into Node Red.